# How can I copy byte parts from a bytearray?

Tags: java, arrays, byte, bitstring

I took a String e.g. "hello" and made it a byte array (str.getBytes()), now I want to take a selection of bits e.g. 5,17,26,...(up to 4 bytes/32 bits) of the byte array made of 8 bit bytes and transform the bit selection into an integer, but I don't have a clue how... nothing really works for me and I don't want to use special libraries.

I tried shifting bits but I don't seem to really understand how this works... Although it might probably be the best way to do it

```
public int[] calcInts(String str) { // str e.g. "hello" or "prhfetg"

byte[] bytes = str.getBytes() // make byte array
selection = 9 // variable - can be greater or smaller than 8 (1 byte)
numOfParts = (str.length*8)/selection  
int[] arr = new int[numOfParts]

for (int i=0; i<numOfParts; i++) { // calculate integers 

// HELP section --> do something with byte array to extract selection

int[i] = (int)... // integer from (max 32bit) selection 
}

return arr;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example, please? If I pass "hello", what should be as result?

Comment: Is this homework or is there somewhere you need the information you try to calculate?

Comment: str = "hello" // 5 chars --> 5 byte / 40 bit;  selection = 5 (could also be greater than 8, like 12 or 25) numOfParts = (str.length*8)/selection // 8 parts --> result = int[8] (array of 8 ints, each made from 5 bits of the 40 bit byte array)

Comment: just practice actually but it makes me crazy...